# difference between routing and controllers on symfony2

Tags: symfony, controller, routes

Hy, I'm really not sure if it's ok to ask this here but i wanna know...

is there a difference between routing and controllers on symfony2?

How should I code my app if I want 2 modules like:

- intro
- blog

should I add both as a routing and a controller? or can I code it as one routing and two controllers?

thanks for the orientation!

regards.

Ok thanks, to clarify what I'm thinking is if I have a large project with tons of different pages it's mean that I should do tons of different routings?

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simplistic way of looking at this: Routing says where pages are, Controllers collect the information that will go on the page and send it to wherever routing says it should go. For the immediate question of Intro & Blog you would probably do best with a controller ([Controller docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html)) for each and routing ([Routing docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html)) for each controller.

Edit in response to question:

It's not clear what is meant by "one routing" but here's what it sounds like.
There is one controller with two routes. Please consult the documentation and base questions on items there that require clarification.

```
/**
 * MySiteController
 * @Route("/", name="home")
 *
 */
class MySiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/intro")
     * @Template("MySite/intro.html.twig")
     */
    public function introAction()
    {
        //Create contents
        $contents = "blah blah";

        return array(
          'contents'  => $contents
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/bog")
     * @Template("MySite/bog.html.twig")
     */

    public function blogAction()
    {
        $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $blog = $opportunities = $em->getRepository('MySiteBundle:Blog')->findAll();

        return array(
            'blog' => $blog,
        );
    }
```

Comment: so, I can put on one routing where all pages are?

Comment: It is not clear what is meant by "one routing".  I've added an example that may provide clarification.

Answer (score 1):

[Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/routing.html) to put in simple terms is what you see in the browser URL, its the path to a 'resource' eg:- www.example.com/blog here blog is a route that is connected with a [Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/controller.html)

A controller is simply a php callable (lets say a method) that is intended for one specific job, to act as a connection between what the user requested and the final output, the controller get the user's request and usually the request is passed to a different php object called services that does one and only one specific task, the processed output-'response' is passed back to the controller and the controller passes it on to the 'view'(lets say html) to be shown to the user

i would say have two different controllers with several 'actions' that holds the actual code that you might write

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/BlogController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog/{slug}", name="blog_show")
     */
    public function showAction($slug)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/IntroController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class IntroController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="intro")
     */
    public function introAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

by one routing if you meant someting like www.example.com/blog/homepage and www.example.com/blog/loginpage where /blog is common for all pages you can use prefixes, put this `@Route("/blog")` above the class name and all routes in that controller will be prefixed with blog

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/ExampleEController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
/**
 * @Route('/example')
 */
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
```